# How to compile special mathematical functions with clang?

Tags: c++, clang++, tr1, cmath

One can call `sph_legendre` from `tr1` and compile it with `gcc-5` or `gcc-6`

```
#include<tr1/cmath>

int main()
{
    std::tr1::sph_legendre(1,1,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, if I try to compile it with `clang++` as:

> clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ legendre.cpp -o legendre

I get

> error: no member named 'sph_legendre' in namespace 'std::tr1'

In the section 40.3, The C++PP (4th edition) states:

> "There is a separate ISO standard for special mathematical functions [C++Math,2010]. An implementation may add these functions to cmath"

How can I compile these special functions with `clang++`?

Comment: Try just `std::sph_legendre`   see the example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_math/sph_legendre . __tr1__ was out in 2005/2007 things have moved on.

Comment: Clang does not ship the TR1. Don't use the TR1.

Comment: @RichardCritten If you run that example `sph_legendre` is not a member of `std` even with `gcc-6.1` and `c++17`

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm trying to find a solution for a piece of code that I didn't write

Comment: @ilciavo: If you absolutely cannot change any of the code, you may be out of luck. You could try to find another TR1 implementer. Not sure if the Boost version can be used as a drop-in replacement. Otherwise, the functions themselves are also implemented in GSL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Richard already mentioned, clang does not support std::sph_legendre at the moment.

A possible workaround for you is to use the boost libraries (http://www.boost.org)
and include header: **boost/math/tr1.hpp**